# send simple email using unix shell command

Tags: email, unix, shell

I am new to unix environment. Well, I just want to send an email using unix shell script. I do not know whether I have rights to do in my user role or not. This is script I tried to run it.

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to send simple email
# email subject
SUBJECT="SET-EMAIL-SUBJECT"
# Email To ?
EMAIL="test@mail.com"
# Email text/message
EMAILMESSAGE="mail.txt"
echo "This is an email message test"> $EMAILMESSAGE
echo "This is email text" >>$EMAILMESSAGE
# send an email using /bin/mail
/bin/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" < $EMAILMESSAGE
```

This script resulted in `0403-006 Execute permission denied`

Can anyone help me to send a simple email using some shell script...

Thanks for you time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the script has its execute permission bits set and that the interpreter in the shebang exists, or that you're invoking it via the interpreter.

Comment: Use `ls -l` to examine the permission bits.

Comment: which gave me something like this:                                               -rwxr-xr-x    3 bin      mail         135550 Apr 08 2009  /bin/mail

Answer (score 0):

The error code `0403-006 Execute permission denied` means (as it says) you don't have permission.

This could be because of one of two reasons

1. The most likley on is that the script doesn't have execute permissions.  Try running:

   ```
   chmod +x /bin/mail
   ```

   This should allow you to execute the file.
2. Other wise you don't have read permissions but because you created the file i doubt that.

Comment: Yes, when I tried to execute the first option that gives the following message: chmod: /bin/mail: Operation not permitted.

Comment: Can not I do this operation in my existing user role? Is anyother way of doing it?

Comment: try `sudo chmod +x /bin/mail`  then type in your user password.  This will run it as a 'root'(ish) user.

Comment: Now no error, but mail not received by recipien. What could be the problem?

Comment: @Mohamed: "mail not received" probably means that mail was disabled on the machine because it is not configured to work correctly.  By changing the permissions on mail without also configuring mail, you are getting mail not sent.  You need to ensure that the machine is configured so that it knows where to send the email for onward delivery.

Answer (score -3):

Remove the double quotes around $EMAIL and $SUBJECT and try again.